# Weblogic 12.2.1 and OpenSaml2 conflict

Tags: java, spring-boot, weblogic, opensaml

I have a spring boot web service application that uses opensaml dependency (an old version, 2.2.3). When I deploy to Weblogic I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
        at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.<clinit>(XMLConfigurator.java:60) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.security.opensaml2.jar:na]
```

The workaround I did is the same as this user: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20913280/2968729. I renamed com.oracle.weblogic.security.opensaml2.jar so it would be ignored.

As described on the error, weblogic has his own `opensaml2.jar` that uses `log4j` which isn't present on my application classpath and that's why fails.

So the point is: I don't want to add log4j neither to use `com.oracle.weblogic.security.opensaml2.jar` but my opensaml from my classpath instead. What is the proper way to achieve this?

weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>ch.qos.logback.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.opensaml</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.cxf</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

I already specify to use opensaml of my classpath so I dont understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So stupid: weblogic.xml was on the wrong place, so it was being ignored. I had it on src/main/resource folder.

It must be on `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml`

Notice there is `webapp` folder!